# Discord.jc / ReferenceError: MessageAttachment is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I get this error and it seems that the bot cannot find an image.

How do I define the path of the image? It is located in: `C:\Users\Yanzi\Desktop\LaisaBot\Emotes`?

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = "!";

client.on("message", function(message) {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    const commandBody = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
    const args = commandBody.split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === "ping") {
        const timeTaken = Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp;
        message.reply(`Pong! This message had a latency of ${timeTaken}ms.`);
    } else if (command === "sum") {
        const numArgs = args.map(x => parseFloat(x));
        const sum = numArgs.reduce((counter, x) => counter += x);
        message.reply(`The sum of all the arguments you provided is ${sum}!`);
    }

    // If the message is '!rip'
    else if (message.content === '!rip') {
        // Create the attachment using MessageAttachment
        const attachment = new MessageAttachment('./laisa2.png');
        // Send the attachment in the message channel with a content
        message.channel.send(`${message.author},`, attachment);
    }
});

client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling MessageAttachment when you have not defined it.

It is part of the Discord libary you required at the top so you have two solutions:

1. Use `new Discord.MessageAttachment` instead of `new MessageAttachment`
2. Where you required Discord at the top replace this with `{ MessageAttachment }`, please be aware that you will also need to add `, client` and others to that object as you are calling `Discord.Client` further up. This will result in `const { MessageAttachment, Client } = require('discord.js');`

I hope this helps, be sure to read the docs and checkout some tutorials.

You can take a look here for info on destructing:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-object-destructuring/

Comment: Might want to add a reference to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment.

Comment: I've used your first solution and it works, thank you! Yeah, i am total noob in js so i am checking guides and documentation of discord js.